# Быстрая сортировка в Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, сортировка

Всем привет.

По запросу "quicksort array Java" гуглится чаще всего такой алгоритм:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = { 9, 2, 4, 7, 3, 7, 10 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));

    int low = 0;
    int high = x.length - 1;

    quickSort(x, low, high);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
}

public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
        return;

    if (low >= high)
        return;

    // pick the pivot
    int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    int pivot = arr[middle];

    // make left < pivot and right > pivot
    int i = low, j = high;
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }

        while (arr[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        if (i <= j) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    // recursively sort two sub parts
    if (low < j)
        quickSort(arr, low, j);

    if (high > i)
        quickSort(arr, i, high);
}
```

}

В связи с этим несколько вопросов:

1) Зачем вообще передается аргумент low, если нижняя граница массива всегда = 0?

2) Опорная точка (middle) высчитывается следующим образом:

```
int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
```

Как мы знаем, low всегда = 0.

Почему если убрать из этого выражения "low +" , то результатом становится StackOverflowError? Как может прибавление ноля на что-то влиять?

```
int middle = (high - low) / 2; --> StackOverflowError
```

3) При этом если вместо

```
int middle = (high - low) / 2;
```

написать

```
int middle = (high + low) / 2;
```

то все работает.
Опять же - каким образом может на что-то влиять сложение ноля вместо вычитания?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нижняя граница массива редко когда 0. Метод `quickSort` рекурсивный. При каждом вызове он разбивает массив на две части и вызывает сам себя для каждой из частей. Так продолжается до тех пора, пока сортируемая часть не станет слишком маленькой. Если убрать `low +` то перестанет работать *базовое ограничение* и метод будет вызывать себя до тех пор, пока не исчерпает стек.